# Problem updating plot according to ipywidget FloatSlider

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to create an interactive `matplotlib.pyplot` plot in jupyter Notebook. I was following along [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SN0Bflf14C4&t=3s). So my goal is to interactively change a plot by changing `ipywidgets` FloatSlider. My code ist almost exactly the same as in the video, besides that I am plotting another mathematical function and I only have two FloatSliders.

I would expect the plot to update accordingly every time I move the FloatSlider (as it does in the video). But nothing happens.

Here is my code:

[image]

I have also tried different backends for matplotlib, but nothing works.

jupyter version:

[image]

Many thanks for any help in advance!

P.S.: here is my code as text:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import *
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

%matplotlib notebook
#nbagg

print(widgets.__version__)
print(matplotlib.__version__)

x = np.linspace(0,30,31)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 4))
plt.suptitle('Weibull-Verteilung f(v)')

def update_plot(k, A):
    
    """
    die Funtion plottet die Kurve erneut, wenn über
    die slider ein Wert geändert wird
    """
        
    # erstmal wieder die Zeichnung löschen
    ax.clear()
    
    # neuen Verlauf berechnen
    f_x = k/A*(x/A)**(k-1)*np.exp(-(x/A)**k)
    
    # und den neuen Verlauf plotten
    ax.bar(x, f_x)
    plt.show()
    
k = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1, max=3, value=2, description='k')
A = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1, max=20, value=6, description='A', position= 200)
   
# sobald einer der slider geändert wird, wird neu geplottet
widgets.interactive(update_plot, k=k, A=A)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not screen shots.

Comment: oh sorry, just edited

Answer (score 0):

And I think, I just found the answer:

I forgot to `display(k, A)`. Now it works!

But strange, the sliders appeared - even without the display command.